# want SKNode to be semi-transparent to sibling nodes, but opaque to background

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, blending

I have several `SKSpriteNodes` that need to be semi-transparent when they intersect each other.  If I set the node's color alpha = 0.5 this works as desired.  But, I don't want the "background" to show through at all.  So the nodes should never blend with the background (ie, the root node).

There is probably a simple technique to accomplish this, but I don't know what it is.

**Update**

Here is an example of what I'm trying to describe with two simple circle nodes.  The circle border has alpha=1.0, the insides are alpha=0.5. As shown the circles blend when overlapped, which is what I want. But then of course they also blend with the background, which is not desired. For the portions that are not overlapped, the inside of the circles should look exactly like the borders.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot example?

Comment: @WangYudong Okay screenshot added.